# Probability Question involving an archer

Tags: probability

> An archer fires an arrow which hits a circular target of radius $2$ metres. Suppose that the arrow is equally likely to hit any point of the target in the sense that the probability that it lies in a given region is proportional to the area of the region. Let A be the distance from the centre of the target to the point the arrow hits. Find the cumulative distribution function of A.

I wasn't able to get my head around this question.

Any Help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The probability of hitting any point within a disk of radius $A$ is:

$$ P(r) = \frac{\pi A^2}{\pi R^2},\quad R= 2m. $$
or
$$ P(r) = \frac{A^2}{4}. $$

Answer (score 0):

A good answer has already already been provided by Hoc Ngo.

If you really want to *feel* the solution to this problem, I recommend you to watch a video by collaboration of [Veritasium](https://www.youtube.com/user/1veritasium) and [Physics Girl](https://www.youtube.com/user/physicswoman) :  [Calculating $\pi$ with Darts](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M34TO71SKGk)

[image]